# Command does not read entire file

Tags: excel, bash, command

I'm having a weird problem. My commands don't read .txt files that I'm saving from Excel. I've tried to save the data in all the available .txt formats available in Excel, but when I run a command it does not read it. Actually it seems to read the first line of the file, but only if the first line of the file contains `Parcela 1`. If I create a plain .txt file from text editor though, it reads it no matter how many lines.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

One of my codes:

```
awk -F"\t" '
{ if ($7 ~ /Parcela 1/)
    print;
else }' source.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: The `else` with no action is superfluous, isn't it?  Your code shown only attempts to print the line(s) containing `Parcela 1`; all others are not printed.  If your problem is that `Parcela 1` appears on line 2 (and not on line 1) and is then not printed, then maybe the problem is in the line endings?  Have you taken a careful look at the `source.txt` file to see what line endings it has?  Have you printed what `awk` reads as `$0`, using perhaps `print "[[" $0 "]]"; before the `if` condition?  The `[[` and `]]` help you see where the ends of the line are and what's in it.

Comment: Please clarify superfluous.
Here is what i have done, and did this with excel too but it did not work.
I opened the file with numbers, copied everything and pasted in a plain text file. The code reads everything perfectly.
I thing my excel has problems...outdated....excel for mac 2008.

Comment: 'Superfluous': _adjective_
unnecessary, especially through being more than enough.  In this case, you could remove the word `else` and your code would behave the same as if it were present.  There's a default action `{ print $0 }` only when the whole of the action is omitted.  Here you have an action block, so there's no default printing behaviour.

Comment: Got it Jonathan. Thanks. Will sure take this surplus away.

Comment: I have Mac Excel 2011, and although I don't recall problems with Mac Excel 2008, I certainly couldn't say now that there were none in this area.  If you want to send me the file as an attachment to an email, look at my profile.  I'm puzzled about what could be going wrong.  I mean primarily the `source.txt` file you created from Excel — rather than the spreadsheet proper.

Comment: Sure, im sending you right now.

Comment: I've sent a response back by email.  We'll need to communicate via email until we can develop an answer for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is virtually certain that the problem is related to Unix vs Windows vs old-style Mac line-endings.  Excel (at least Excel 2008 and 2011 on Mac) can write files in a variety of formats.  None of these has 'Unix native' line endings.

For example, using Excel 2011, I got:

```
$ file *.dif *.csv *.txt *.prn | sort
Data Interchange Format.dif:         Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
MS-DOS Comma Separated.csv:          Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CR line terminators
MS-DOS Formatted Text.txt:           Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CR line terminators
Space Delimited Text.prn:            Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CR line terminators
Tab Delimited Text.txt:              Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CR line terminators
UTF-16 Unicode Text.txt:             Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
Windows Comma Separated.csv:         ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators
Windows Formatted Text.txt:          ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators
$ ule *.dif *.csv *.txt *.prn | sort
Data Interchange Format.dif: 2301 DOS, No final EOL
MS-DOS Comma Separated.csv: 103 Mac, No final EOL
MS-DOS Formatted Text.txt: 103 Mac, No final EOL
Space Delimited Text.prn: 104 Mac
Tab Delimited Text.txt: 103 Mac, No final EOL
UTF-16 Unicode Text.txt: 103 Unix, 103 Mac, No final EOL, 11019 null bytes
Windows Comma Separated.csv: 103 DOS, No final EOL
Windows Formatted Text.txt: 103 DOS, No final EOL
$
```

The file names correspond to the save format chosen from the Excel drop-down box.  The output from `file` shows that the none of the formats are standard Unix text files.  The `ule` (Uniform Line Endings) program is one of my own devising; it was used in its default 'check' mode.  It is interesting that most of the files to not have a final end of line sequence; the data stops without a final newline.

```
$ ule -h
Usage: ule [-bcdhmnosuzV] [file ...]
  -b  Create backups of the files
  -c  Check line endings (default)
  -d  Convert to DOS (CRLF) line endings
  -h  Print this help and exit
  -m  Convert to MAC (CR) line endings
  -n  Ensure line ending at end of file
  -o  Overwrite original files
  -s  Write output to standard output (default)
  -u  Convert to Unix (LF) line endings
  -z  Check for zero (null) bytes
  -V  Print version information and exit

$
```

On Unix systems, lines end with the newline (NL — aka LF or linefeed) character.  On Windows, normally lines end with CRLF, carriage return and linefeed; on classic Mac OS (before Mac OS X), and apparently for MS-DOS with the Office products, the lines end with just CR, carriage return.

`awk` reads lines.  If you try to process one of the files with only CR line endings, awk will consider that the file contains a single line.  If you try to process one of the files with CRLF line endings, awk will recognize the lines OK (they end at the LF), but will consider the CR to be part of the last field.

So, depending on what you're really after, you should be using one of the 'Windows*' formats.  The 'Parcela 1' lines are 92, 99 and 102 in those files.

```
awk -F"\t" '{ if ($7 ~ /Parcela 1/) print; }' "Windows Formatted Text.txt"
                9/6/19        (Parcela 1)FINANCIAMENTO FATURA JULHO EM 4X    (Dividido)        "($1,052.38)"
                9/6/19        (Parcela 1)ROUPAS GUI    6.1.1.10 - DESPESAS PESSOAIS:6.1.1.10.004 - VESTUARIO        ($44.70)
                9/6/19        "(Parcela 1)TROCA 2 PNEUS DIANTEIROS, BALANCEAMENTO E ALINHAMENTO FOX"    6.1.1.02 - TRANSPORTE:6.1.1.02.001 - AUTOMOVEL:6.1.1.02.001 - MANUTENCAO    ($282.68)
```

Any of the other formats is going to give problems in some shape or form, until you massage them into a format that is recognized by `awk`, e.g. by running:

```
tr '\r' '\n' < "MS-DOS Comma Separated Text.csv" > "Unix Comma Separated Text.csv"
```

You can then apply awk to the "Unix Comma Separated Text.csv" file safely.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, could please give me a hand?
When i run this code for modifying from DOS to Unix format, it returns a message "Illegal byte sequence", which actually does not seem to be a big deal since the file is generated anyway in Unix format and is processed by the awk command. The only thing thats happening is that the last line of the new file is missing information. Ex:

Last line of the file to be processed:

30/05/2016  PGTO VISA ITAUCARD TransferÍncia R$ 2.306,16  [De: 1.1.1.02.001 - ITAU 12399-0]

Thats the result of the output:

30/05/2016  PGTO VISA ITAUCARD Transfer

Comment: On the face of it, the data is encoded in a single-byte code set such as ISO 8859-1 but the scanning code thinks it should be in UTF-8, so the 'Í' is causing trouble.  More accurately than that is going to be hard to say without a byte-by-byte dump of the data in hex format, or something similar — and information about the locale(s) you're working with.

Comment: I discovered the problem is happening because an accent "ˆ", in letter "e", in the word "Transferência". How do i tell this command to ignore that symbol. Is there a way?

Comment: It might be best to convert from the original 8859-1 code set to UTF8.  The `iconv` program can do that, perhaps. Or maybe you need to be more selective than that program is.  I'm not sure what the best way to deal with removing/ignoring `ê` is.  You could use `tr` to delete it.  The 8859-1 code point for `ê` is 0xEA (octal 352).  Hence: `tr -d '\352'` might do the job — but it gave me 'illegal byte sequence' errors.  So, you'd need to persuade `tr` you're using 8859-1, etc.  That all gets messy: `LC_ALL=en_us.8859-1 tr -d '\352'`.  That seemed to work, but I don't make claims for 'best'.